# dependency resolution pip virtualenv

Tags: python, dependencies, virtualenv, pip

I have 2 local libraries which are dependent on different version of suds.

Example -

- Module-A-1.0's setup.py has a requirement of suds ==0.3.9.
- Module-B-1.0's setup.py has a requirement of suds ==0.4.0.

Both these modules are required by Module-C, which has the following its setup.py

- django
- Module-A-1.0
- Module-B-1.0

Module-C will be installed in a virtualenv using pip. **My question is which version of suds will be installed and can I have both versions installed in the same virtual env?**

What I noticed was, whichever module I specified first in the setup.py for Module-C, that version of suds gets installed. So in this case suds 0.3.9. If I switched the modules to

- django
- Module-B-1.0
- Module-A-1.0

The version of suds that gets installed in suds-0.4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pip + virtualenv you can't have two versions of a library installed at the same time.

And, unfortunately, I don't know of any good ways of handling this situation. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks David. So does that mean which version of suds gets installed depends on the order of place things in setup.py? I am coming the maven world where if 2 libs with different versions exist, the latest one will be picked up. Is that not the case here as well?

Comment: Yes, you're right – it will be the last one which ends up installed. You can check by running `pip freeze | grep suds` or `python` then `import suds; suds.__version__`.

Comment: No problem. At some point, you should accept my answer by clicking the checkmark under the up/down arrows on the left, and possibly give an upvote too.